# No Debug Symbols - aarch64-linux-gnu-ld

Tags: arm64, raspberry-pi4

When assembling an ASM program (Raspberry Pi 4) with:

```
aarch64-linux-gnu-as -ggdb -L -o main.o -acdhlmns=main.lst main.asm
```

Then linking with (I know the `-g` is just for compatibility with other tools):

```
aarch64-linux-gnu-ld -g -s -o main main.o
```

When using `gdb` to debug the main executable `gdb ./main`, I get this:

```
No debugging symbols found in ./main
```

If I issue the command file `./main.o`, the symbols are in the object file, but they don't get into the executable file. The main executable runs fine without `gdb`.

Any ideas?  I've spent three hours on this so far and am at my wits end.  :-)

```
aarch64-linux-gnu-as -ggdb -L -o main.o -acdhlmns=main.lst main.asm
aarch64-linux-gnu-ld -g -s -o main main.o
gdb ./main
```

Expected, debug symbols in the executable.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The -s in the aarch64-linux-gnu-ld parameters means strip. One of its functions is to remove the debug symbols. Get rit of -s and gdb will no longer complain about this.